# Docker logs sent to Cloud logging are displayed in strange format

Tags: docker, logging, cloud, gcloud

I am running a VM instance on GCloud with few Docker containers inside. All containers write logs via gcplogs and I access them in the cloud logging explorer.

Anyway, all fine, except the logs from one of the containers are oddly formatted. For example, when I check the logs in the Docker container, all of them seems fine, as shown here:

> 9:13PM DBG updating supply height=308 module=bank

when I browse the same container logs in the cloud logging explorer, the same log.message looks like:

> [90m9:13PM[0m [33mDBG[0m updating supply [36mheight=[0m308 [36mmodule=[0mbank

Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 1):

Those funny characters are **[ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)**. They are used to highlight and colorize text when displayed on a terminal window or monitor.